# decoding an UTF-8 json file with PHP

Tags: php, json, decoding

this is a sample of a single JSON ELEMENT i read from the json file with PHP

```
{  
   "Air Elemental":{  
      "layout":"normal",
      "name":"Air Elemental",
      "manaCost":"{3}{U}{U}",
      "cmc":5,
      "colors":[  
         "Blue"
      ],
      "type":"Creature — Elemental",
      "types":[  
         "Creature"
      ],
      "subtypes":[  
         "Elemental"
      ],
      "text":"Flying",
      "power":"4",
      "toughness":"4",
      "imageName":"air elemental"
   }
```

And this is the PHP output (var_dump) of the same JSON ITEM

```
public 'type' => string 'Creature â€” Elemental' (length=22)
```

As you can see the (—) becomes (â€”).

How i can solve this encoding problem? (After reading the json i write the data on DB)